# Дедукция возвращаемого типа у оператора преобразования

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++, gcc, language-lawyer

Почему следующий код компилируется?

```
template<class>
struct A {
  operator auto() {
    return 42;
  }
};

int main() {
  int a = A<int>{};
}
```

А этот не компилируется?

```
struct A {
  template<class>
  operator auto() {
    return 42;
  }
};

int main() {
  int a = A{};
}
```

> error: no viable conversion from 'A' to 'int'

Использую `gcc`. Что интересно, в `msvc` первый код также не компилируется. Почему?

> error C3177: you cannot have a conversion function to a type that
> contains 'auto'

Comment: Ошибку компиляции было бы неплохо привести.

Comment: @gbg ....привёл

Comment: В VС++  и первый не компилируется.

Comment: @Harry действительно, указал в вопросе

Comment: вы пытаетесь вызвать не шаблонный оператор, но у вас есть только шаблонный. Нужно дописать еще специализацию(и)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan как?

Comment: То, что он не компилируется, выглядит логичным. Ведь его нельзя будет вызвать, так как при вызове оператора преобразования нельзя будет указать параметр шаблона. Мне представляется это тот случай, когда шаблон является ill-formed, no diagnostic is required. vc++ дает ошибку, g++ предупреждение, а clang просто забивает

Comment: @user7860670 вы про какой вариант? Первый работает и в gcc, и в clang, но не работает в msvc. Второй не работает нигде.

Comment: про второй, и про второй до редактирования. в первом варианте оператор не содержит параметров шаблона, которые надо было бы указывать при его вызове

Comment: @user7860670 со вторым до редактирования всё в порядке, имхо. Потому что там никак не используется шаблонный оператор, а значит компилироваться должно. Хотя не уверен что это правило распространяется на шаблонные операторы, но для обычных шаблонных функций-членов это было бы нормально. Задам ещё вопрос на эту тему, тут это немного оффтоп.

Comment: Конкретно для оператора преобразования никак, тем более с автоматическим определением типа. Нельзя написать такой оператор. И не только нельзя, это  не  поддается никакой логике...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему следующий код компилируется?
>
> ```
> operator auto() {
>   return 42;
> }
> ```

Здесь `auto` автоматически определяет возвращаемый тип, как в `auto foo() {return 42;}`. То есть он заменяется на `int`.

> Что интересно, в msvc первый код также не компилируется. Почему?

Видимо баг. (Это же MSVC.)

> А этот не компилируется?
>
> ```
> template<class>
> operator auto() {
>   return 42;
> }
> ```

В стандарте есть прямой запрет на шаблонный `operator auto`: [`[class.conf.fct]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.fct#6).

Если делаете `operator <тип>` шаблоном, то шаблонный параметр должен упоминаться в `<тип>`е, иначе как компилятор будет его выводить?

(Кстати интересно, что `A a; a.operator auto();` работает, а `A a; a.operator auto<int>();` почему-то нет...)

Comment: Вот с последним мне и непонятно, почему бы не разрешить вызывать его явно, так как вы указали. А сам шаблонный параметр ведь в операторе никак не используется, можно было бы теоретически вывести `int` опять.

Comment: а вы сами попробуйте это анализировать... Что такое auto<int>?

Comment: @oiq Не знаю, но пользы от этого немного. Можно с тем же успехом сделать обычную функцию-шаблон.