# Корректность кода с заведомо неверными шаблонными функциями-членами

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, language-lawyer

```
struct A {
    template<class T>
    void foo() {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0);
    }
};

#include <type_traits>

struct B {
    template<class T>
    std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) == 0, void>
    foo() {
        ;
    }
};

struct C {
    template<class>
    operator auto() {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main() {
  auto a = A{};
  auto b = B{};
  auto c = C{};
}
```

Почему этот код [компилируется без предупреждений в `clang`](https://godbolt.org/z/vFYF4j), [компилируется с предупреждением в `gcc`](https://godbolt.org/z/3MWrbq), [не компилируется в `msvc`](https://godbolt.org/z/D3YKzH)?

Разве то, что шаблонные функции-члены не вызываются, не делает этот код корректным? Касается ли это шаблонных операторов? Касается ли это только шаблонного оператора преобразования?

Предупреждение в `gcc`:

> warning: use of 'auto' in member template conversion operator can
> never be deduced

Ошибка в `msvc`:

> error C3177: you cannot have a conversion function to a type that
> contains 'auto'

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1148800/396632.

Comment: случай С уже же разобрали

Comment: @user7860670 *шаблон является ill-formed, no diagnostic is required*? Можно ссылку на соответствующий пункт стандарта?

Comment: на случай С же есть явный запрет, [приведенный](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.fct#6) в предыдущем вопросе

Comment: @user7860670 означает ли это, что само написание такого кода уже делает программу ill-formed, или она становится ill-formed только при вызове такого кода?

Comment: Меня вообще страшно смущает `operator auto()` - ведь в данном случае `auto` не вывод типа возвращаемого значения, а оператор приведения типа, нет? И *откуда* выводить этот тип? Из присваивания? в самом операторе информации недостаточно. Imho, конечно, и искать в стандарте подтверждение этому имху я не буду, фиг найду...

Comment: нет, тут одно только объявление делает программу невалидной @Harry его уже нашли выше...

Comment: @Harry Похоже все-таки вывод возвращаемого типа (из `return 42;`, как в обычной функции). Я сначала подумал, что `operator auto` - это сразу шаблон (даже без `template`), но нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` и `B` - ill-formed, no diagnostic required из-за [`[temp.res]/8.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.1). (Код неправильный, но ошибка или предупреждение не гарантируются.)

`C` - ill-formed из-за [`[class.conf.fct]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.fct#6). (Должен вызывать ошибку или предупреждение, иначе компилятор не соответствует стандарту.)

Comment: С `A` и `B` согласен. Но почему `C` ill-formed с диагностикой? Там вроде бы просто написано ***shall not have** a deduced return type*.

Comment: @oiq [Тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) написано, что нарушение "shall" делает программу ill-formed (без "no diangostic required"). По хорошему, надо в стандарте подтверждение поискать...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25302808

Answer (score 0):

В языке предусмотрена масса правил, согласно которым шаблон может делать программу невалидной (с диагностикой или без) еще до инстанцирования, или даже в отсутствии такового, или даже если сам шаблон валидный.

- К объявлению и определению шаблона применяются обычные проверки синтаксиса в несколько сокращенном объеме, насколько позволяет двухфазный поиск имен. В этом примере еще до инстанцирования компилятор имеет возможность определить, что `T::bar` не является именем типа, что делает конструкцию `T::bar x{};` и весь шаблон невалидным:

```
template<typename T> void
foo(void) { T::bar x{}; }
```

Объявление шаблонного оператора преобразования, в котором параметр шаблона должен выводится, как раз относится к этой группе - такой оператор не разрешен согласно *11.4.7.2.6 Conversion functions [class.conv.fct]*. Поведение gcc и clang в этом случае неконформное.

- К шаблонам также применяется рад специальных правил, описанных в *13.8 Name resolution [temp.res]* и делающих программу невалидной, но при этом не требующих диагностики от компилятора. В эту категорию попадает пример с `B`, в котором никакой вариант инстанцирования `B::foo` не будет валидным.
- К шаблонам применяются обычные правила, касающиеся единственности определения. В этом примере поведение программы не определено, хотя шаблоны сами по себе валидные:

```
// одна единица трансляции
template<typename T> class
Foo{ public: int m_x{}; };
Foo<int> x{};
// другая единица трансляции
template<typename T> class
Foo{ protected: int m_x{}; };
Foo<int> x{};
```

- К шаблонам применяются ряд специальных правил, описанных в *13.7.6.1 Function template overloading [temp.over.link]* и делающих программу невалидной, но при этом не требующих диагностики от компилятора, хотя шаблоны сами по себе валидны и не инстанцируются. В этом примере шаблоны `f` являются функционально эквивалентными, но различны:

```
template<int x>
class A{};

template<int I> void
f(A<I>, A<I+2>) {}

template<int I> void
f(A<I>, A<I+1+1>) {}
```